# Should questions that are asked more than a certain period of time be reopened again automatically for re-evaluation?

Tags: discussion

I have seen many questions where the answer is relevant to the time that the question is asked, so if a significant amount of time passes then the answer may no longer be relevant. However, rather than asking a separate question based on a different time period, wouldn't it be better to make questions like that less time sensitive and reopen them for discussion periodically? Should we be trying to distinguish between these 'best practice' or 'current standard/view' questions from more specific questions where the answer is unlikely to change?

Comment: I think I know what you're talking about, but could you give a couple of examples?